# S3 read Sagemaker trained model

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

Using Amazon Sagemaker, I created an Xgboost model. After unpacking the resulting tar.gz file, I end up with a file "xgboost-model".

The next step will be to upload the model directly from my S3 bucket, without downloading it using *pickle*. Here is what I tried:

```
obj = client.get_object(Bucket='...',Key='xgboost-model')

xgb_model = pkl.load(open((obj['Body'].read())),"rb")
```

But it throws me the error:

```
TypeError: embedded NUL character
```

Also tried this:

```
xgb_model = pkl.loads(open((obj['Body'].read())),"rb")
```

the outcome was the same.

Another approach:

```
bucket='...'
key='xgboost-model'

with s3io.open('s3://{0}/{1}'.format(bucket, key),mode='w') as s3_file:
  pkl.dump(mdl, s3_file)
```

This giving the error:

```
CertificateError: hostname bucket doesn't match either of '*.s3.amazonaws.com', 's3.amazonaws.com'
```

This although the bucket is the same.

How Can I upload the model in a pickle object so I can then use it it for predictions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My assumption is you have trained the model using Sagemaker XGBoost built-in algorithm. You would like to use that model and do the predictions in your own hosting environment (not Sagemaker hosting).

`pickle.load(file)` reads a pickled object from the open file object file and `pickle.loads(bytes_object)` reads a pickled object from a bytes object and returns the deserialized object. Since you have the S3 object already downloaded (into memory) as bytes, you can use `pickle.loads` without using `open`

```
xgb_model = pkl.loads(obj['Body'].read())
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. However now I encounter a different error with your suggestion : `UnpicklingError: invalid load key, 'n'.`

Comment: Did you pickle your model before uploading to S3? I think you are trying to unpickle model which is not pickled before.

Comment: No, I did not pickle it. A little strange, but if I load the resulting sagemaker object with _pkl.load_ it works. But If I put that object on S3 as it is and call it as above, I will get that error. I`ll try again to unzip, pickle, upload to S3 and load it and see it will work.

Comment: It worked with pickle-ing the model before uploading it to S3. Thanks!

Comment: I'm trying to unpickle an object from s3, but I'm getting `TypeError: scalar() argument 1 must be numpy.dtype, not numpy.dtype' attributes` when I run `model = pickle.loads(response['Body'].read())`. If anyone has any suggestions, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If you have trained the model using SageMaker's XGBoost built-in algorithm at one point and would like to use that model to do predictions in a Sagemaker environment at a later stage you use the estimator's 'attach' method.

Right after you fitted XGBoost you can use

```
model_job_name = xgb_model._current_job_name
```

to determine the training job's name. Alternatively you can go to the 'training job' section of the SageMaker dashboard and find the name of the job that you ran:
[training job dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCUwc.png)

Later when you want to reuse the model you do:

```
import sagemaker
reloaded_xgb_model = sagemaker.estimator.Estimator.attach(model_job_name)
```